# make sum column and show result beside field

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table like this
[image]

and the output what I want
[image]

Where NETT2 is sum of value of TRX_NUMBER, and i only want to use SUM, no matter what i use CASE

Can is possible ?

I tried like this

```sql
select segment1 
,jenis_rcv
,gl_date
,trx_number
,nett
,sum(nett) nett2
from SEMUA
group by segment1 
,jenis_rcv
,gl_date
,trx_number
,nett
```

Comment: Please clarify, why is the value of `NETT2` zero in your required output? Why, if you want the sum of the values of `TRX_NUMBER`, have you used the `sum` aggregate function on the `NETT` column?

Comment: the value of NETT2 is come from SUM(NETT), when you add all value of TRX_NUMBER the result is 0. But when i tried like that (SUM), the result of NETT2 is same like NETT. I want the result of NETT2 is zero and filled all the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **SUM** analytic function with a **PARTITION BY** but without an **ORDER BY** clause.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SUM.html#GUID-5610BE2C-CFE5-446F-A1F7-B924B5663220

```
sum(nett) over (partition by trx_number) nett2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need `gl_date` in your output because you are summing across all dates:

```sql
select segment1 
,jenis_rcv
,trx_number
,nett
,sum(nett) nett2
from SEMUA
group by segment1 
,jenis_rcv
,trx_number
,nett
```

Keeping `gl_date` makes things a little more complicated, you need to use a `PARTITION BY` to explain what to sum over:

```sql
select segment1 
,jenis_rcv
,gl_date
,trx_number
,SUM(nett)
OVER (PARTITION BY segment1 
,jenis_rcv
,trx_number
ORDER BY gl_date) as nett2
FROM SEMUA
```

Comment: Made some edits, I hadn't got the partition clause quite correct